# Having trouble displaying the graph to break out different series upon loading then based on user selection

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a dashboard where a user can compare performances of certain product groups or add multiple groups together and see an aggregated performance.

However, the initial graph displayed has multiple values in each x axis and the incorrect graph doesn't change based on product group a user would select.

Snippet of data:

```
structure(list(Order_Year = c("2019", "2020", "2019", "2020", 
"2019", "2020", "2019", "2020", "2019", "2020"), Order_Month = c("01", 
"01", "02", "02", "03", "03", "04", "04", "05", "05"), Category = c("Furniture", 
"Furniture", "Furniture", "Furniture", "Furniture", "Furniture", 
"Furniture", "Furniture", "Furniture", "Furniture"), Sales = c(7698, 
7246, 3926, 9212, 12799, 12993, 13216, 11416, 15123, 22800)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Pulling in the superstore data 
superstore_sales <- read_csv("superstore_sales.csv")
  
# Extracting the year/month for easier time attribute time wrangling
superstore_sales$order_date_year <- str_sub(superstore_sales$order_date, -4,-1)
superstore_sales$order_date_month <- str_sub(superstore_sales$order_date, -7, -6)

#renaming the new columns
colnames(superstore_sales)[24] <- "Order_Year"
colnames(superstore_sales)[25] <- "Order_Month"

sales_graph1 <- aggregate(superstore_sales$sales, by = list(superstore_sales$Order_Year, superstore_sales$Order_Month, superstore_sales$category), sum, na.rm = TRUE)

#renaming the new columns
colnames(sales_graph1)[1] <- "Order_Year"
colnames(sales_graph1)[2] <- "Order_Month"
colnames(sales_graph1)[3] <- "Category"
colnames(sales_graph1)[4] <- "Sales"
  
ui <- fluidPage(
  #main header in the dashboard
  titlePanel("Superstore Performance Summary"),
  #row 1 for information
  wellPanel( fluidRow(
    #title for graph 1
    "Overall Performance",
      sidebarPanel(
                 pickerInput(inputId = "Category",
                             label = "Category",
                             choices = unique(sales_graph1$Category),
                             options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                             multiple = TRUE)
                 ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
            )),
  #row 2 for information
  wellPanel( fluidRow("TBD"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    #creating the desired line graph
    ggplot(sales_graph1, aes(x = Order_Month, y = Sales, group = input$Category)) + geom_line()
    
  })
  
}
  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try with filtering your data for the selected categories, e.g. `subset(sales_graph1, Category %in% input$Category) |> ggplot(aes(x = Order_Month, y = Sales, group = Category)) + geom_line()`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`, e.g. run `dput(head(sales_graph1, 10))` and copy & paste the output into your post.

Comment: Edited the post with the dput() output! Do you other areas I can look into?

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in my comment the first issue is that you have to filter the data for the selected categories. Second issue is that there are multiple values for each `Order_Month`, i.e. one for each `Order_Year`. Hence, to account for that I map `Order_Year` on the `color` aes and additionally we have to group by both `Category` and `Order_Year` which could be achieved via `interaction():`

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # main header in the dashboard
  titlePanel("Superstore Performance Summary"),
  # row 1 for information
  wellPanel(fluidRow(
    # title for graph 1
    "Overall Performance",
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "Category",
        label = "Category",
        choices = unique(sales_graph1$Category),
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
  )),
  # row 2 for information
  wellPanel(fluidRow("TBD"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    subset(sales_graph1, Category %in% input$Category) |>
      ggplot(
        aes(
          x = Order_Month, y = Sales, color = Order_Year,
          group = interaction(Category, Order_Year)
        )
      ) +
      geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]